# version of node js upgradation 6 to 8 error

Tags: node.js, linux, centos6

I am trying to update node package upgradation on cent os 6.10final from v6.14.3 to 8.11.3

### I have followed below step.

List available node versions =>

n ls

Install a specific version =>

### sudo n 8.11.3

but still it showing old 6.14.3 version.

sudo n 8.11.3

```
 install : node-v8.11.3
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.11.3
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.11.3/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

################################################################## 100.0%

installed : v6.14.3

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use node version manager (aka nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

You can easily pick whichever version you want with that tool.

Comment: Hello Rafael,
I want to upgrade now, please do suggest if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this NVM (Node Version Manager) to manage your node versions. It's very useful and it's a great tool to manage your node versions.

To install NVM, run this script on your console:

curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash

Then, to download the latest release of node the following two commands:

nvm install node
nvm use node

Install a specific version of node, you can simply run:

nvm install v8.9.0
nvm use v8.9.0

It works thanks.